# Broke my Minecraft Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, mcedit

[image]I just spent 6 hours building a giant hole under the entire End in Minecraft. I am in 1.8 because I like that version and it has my server. But, I wanted to change the floor to dirt with tall grass, so I did the fill command and made the floor dirt, then I did the fill command for tall grass and now every time I join, the server shuts down.
My friend joined and went to the end now he cant join. I went to Mc edit and changed the blocks to stone but there is this weird green stuff and I can't figure out what to do. Please help. By the way, I have no idea how to use Mc edit.[image: the weird green stuff under end (i think causing crashing)]

Comment: Seems you have replaced too many blocks. Try deleting the end to let the server create a new one.

Comment: how do i delete the end?

Comment: I'm sorry i am not very good at this kind of thing. is the end is my server world file?

Comment: Are you sure you have a *server* and not just a local game shared with your friend?

Comment: this is a server right? we are not local.

Comment: friends are not on same internet>

Comment: try moving DIM1 folder out of the world folder

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you i dont know what that did but it worked the end just got reloaded. It doesnt have what i spent time on but that can be rebuilt. thank you

Comment: If you found a solution to your question, please post it, to allow others to remedy it if it occurs to them. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0):

The Nether and End can both be reset.

In your server directory is a folder named *world*. This one contains all the world files, including the other two dimensions.

If you (re)move *DIM-1* from it, your Nether will be reset and doing the same with *DIM1* will reset the End. Everything you have done there will be gone, like if it never happened.

The server must be closed/stopped in order to do so correctly. With the next start the files will be recreated from the scratch. And as usual: Make a backup. Never delete something without proper backup.